# Create column and get the last data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following data:

[image]

How can I get the column "Stock" and "Cost"?. The stock column is the sum of movements of quantity and cost column is the last average cost on the month.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @alerodrigueziv Then add the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select 
    t.*,
    sum(tranQty) over(order by tranDate) stock,
    case 
        when row_number() over(partition by year(tranDate), month(tranDate) order by tranDate desc) = 1
        then mtlUnitCost
    end cost
from mytable t
```

Comment: How can I get the same cost on null fields according to the month?

Comment: @alerodrigueziv: I don't know what you mean. As far as I see, the query does produce the result that you expect for the sample data that you showed, isn't it the case?